# Bulk update using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

The following calls DB every time to get the list of users by id.

```
foreach (User user in users)
{
    db.Users.Where(w => users.Any(a => a.Id == w.Id)).ToList().
     ForEach(x => {
         x.name = user.name;
         x.cat = user.cat;
         
      });                

}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Is there a way to do this with out going in the loop each time.

Comment: Get all the users with a single query using `IN`? Get some of the users with a batch strategy? There are plenty of ways, depending on the size of the data

Comment: A more efficient way would be to use a join: `foreach (var x in db.Users.Join(users, dbUser => dbUser.Id, user => user.Id, (dbUser, user) => (dbUser, user)) { x.dbUser.name = user.name; x.dbUser.cat = user.cat; }`.

Comment: @ckuri Using a JOIN between a database query and an in-memory list? Even if that did work, which I think it doesn't, it would get all users into memory and do the join in memory

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto the list has 25k+ objects.

Comment: Which ORM do you use?

Comment: @user619969 For 25k objects, probably the best is not to do this in memory at all

Comment: What is the DBMS? If it is MS Sql Server consider using ADO.NET and a [Table Valued Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters). That would change it into a single call to the database instead of 25k + 1 (for the update).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the list of users first, update them, then save changes.  You would still need a foreach to update it though.  This takes the List and selects only the Id, turning it into List (or whatever your ID field is), then gets all the users in that list from the database, updates them, and saves.

```
var dbUserList = db.Users.Where(x => users.Select(y => y.Id).Contains(x.Id));
foreach (var user in users)
{
     var dbUser = dbUserList.First(x => x.Id == user.Id);
     dbUser.name = user.name;
     dbUser.cat = user.cat;
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hints: drop the `.ToList()` to have a more efficient query, replace `Find` with `Single`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Agree on the `.ToList()`.  Isn't `Find` faster than `Single` though, as `Single` iterates over the entire list while `Find` stops after it finds a match?

Comment: `Find` is from `List<T>`, it doesn't exist as extension for `IEnumerable<T>`. You are right though, that should be `First` - I'm just used to `.Single()` when it comes to searches for Id :)

Comment: A plain old SQL query would be even more efficient.

Comment: your for loops assumes that it has found all the users from the database. I would suggest to loop through `dbUserList ` and Do `single` to `users`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Completely agreed, but this would be just fine if it was 10 items (as could be assumed before the OP's comment on the 25k size of the list)